# Variable naming rule in python

Tags: python

Can a space be given in variable naming. I tried a python program but it's showing an error I have attached the screenshot of the same.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHFsg.png)

Comment: Have you not answered your own question? You can see the definition of identifiers here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

Comment: No, it can't. Use underscore `_`

Comment: No you can't, the common convention is to use `snake_case` for variables and function names and to use `PascalCase` for class names.

Answer (score -1):

You can't give a space. It's violating the naming convention. What you can do, add underscore (_) between words. Here is the correction:

```py
Gal_Gadot = "Gal Gadot"
print(Gal_Gadot);
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: "Violating the convention" would be e.g. `Names_Like_This`. Spaces in identifiers are invalid syntax.

Comment: What i mean is that against the naming convention. Simply means that it can't!

Comment: The naming conventions are https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions. They are all *within* what is syntactically valid.

Comment: Please don’t *answer* questions with a screenshot!

Comment: Noted with thanks. I have updated my answer.